# Snakemake using the first argument of a list as a wildcard

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to run the analysis in snakemake where as a proband I take always the first bam file present in the list, i.e `NUM_194` and `NUM_123`. Is there a way to use as a wildcards the first IDENTIFIER of the bam file of the `list(d)` in the proband line?

```
d = {"FAM_194": ["path/to/NUM_194/NUM_194.bam", "path/to/NUM_195/NUM_195.bam", "path/to/NUM_196/NUM_196.bam"],
     "FAM_123": ["path/to/NUM_123/NUM_123.bam", "path/to/NUM_126/NUM_126.bam", "path/to/NUM_127/NUM_127.bam"]}
     
FAMILIES = list(d)

rule all:
    input:
        ...
        
wildcard_constraints:
    family = "|".join(FAMILIES)

.....some other rules 

rule SelectVariants:
    input:
        invcf="{fam}/{fam}.vcf"
    params:
        ref="myref.fasta"
    output:
        out="{fam}/{fam}.proband.vcf",
        out2="{fam}/{fam}.p.avinput"
    shell:
        """
        proband=NUM_194 <--- the first sample of the list(d), for example NUM_194
        gatk --java-options "-Xms2G -Xmx2g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2" SelectVariants -R {params.ref} -V {input.invcf} -sn "$proband" -O {output.out}
        convert2annovar -format vcf4 --includeinfo {output.out} > {output.out2}
        """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using a [function as input](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#input-functions) (lambda function here) like this?

```
rule SelectVariants:
    input:
        invcf="{fam}/{fam}.vcf",
        proband= lambda wc: d[wc.fam][0],
    ...
    shell:
        """
        gatk ... -sn {input.proband} ...
        """
```

Comment: thanks! I think this is taking the whole path path/to/NUM_194/NUM_194.bam, while I need only NUM_194. Should I use some sed?

Comment: `echo "{input.proband}" | sed ...` is an option. Bash [basename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) could be a simpler solution. LIke:  `basename {input.proband} .bam`

Comment: this basename option is a very nice solution and solved me many other issues where I was using sed :) thanks!