# A way to iterate over one rule by changing an index in the filename using wildcards (in snakemake)

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am attempting to create an iterative rule in snakemake. I have an empty text file in data/ called basic_0. I am hoping to apply a rule to it "x" times (where "x" is an integer) by calling `$ snakemake data/basic_<x>.txt --cores 1`, where the snakefile is as follows:

```
rule iterative_addHi:
    input:
        "data/basic_{iter}.txt"
    output:
        "data/basic_{iter+1}.txt"
    shell:
        "python addHi.py {input} {output}"
```

The addHi.py file just adds a new line with "Hi" to the text file (just toy code), so if I call `$ snakemake data/basic_5.txt --cores 1` I would hope to find a file called data/basic_5.txt that has five new lines with "Hi". However I'm only getting

> MissingRuleException: No rule to produce data/basic_5.txt (if you use
> input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected
> exceptions).

Is there a way to do what I'm thinking? I've tried converting the wildcard into an integer using `int()`, then adding 1, then converting this back to a string using `str()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Snakemake allows expressing inputs as a function of wildcards. This applies to inputs directive, so the arithmetic should be moved from `output` to `input` and lambda used to delay the computation/evaluation of inputs:

```py
rule iterative_addHi:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: f"data/basic_{int(wildcards.iter)-1}.txt"
    output:
        "data/basic_{iter}.txt"
    shell:
        "python addHi.py {input} {output}"
```

As @dariober noted in a comment: the wildcards are stored as strings, so for arithmetic, we need to convert them to an integer representation.

Comment: +1, really cool! Minor bug: The string formatting should be `{int(wildcards.iter)-1}` to convert string to int first.